# Import Go program source as library

Tags: import, go

I have found code on github in Go and want to use it as library in my program. Unfortunately, whole code is in "main" package. Is there any way how I can import the code as library without changing that code?

Answer (score 1):

No. Fork the repo, and fix it to work as a library, or if it's simple enough, copy the files directly into your main package.

Answer (score 0):

you can import it as a separate package, something like:

```
import sth "path/to/your/package"
```

Comment: this is not allowed, and results in the error `import "path/to/your/package" is a program, not an importable package`

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

Agree with @JimB - fork repo and change it like 'package main' > 'package lib' and import in your code like that:

```
package main

import L "somelib"

func main() {
    L.SomeFunc()
}
```

etc..